# what's the simplest way to increment the numbers in this string 01:02:99 in unix?

Tags: shell, arithmetic

What is the simplest way to increment the numbers in this string `01:02:99`?

Expected output: `01:03:00`

I'm hoping for a `sed` response, but I don't think it would be simple.

Comment: What would that "01:02:99" be? Is it a shell variable ?

Comment: What is that, time? a date? what's the incremented value then?

Comment: integer. my mistake

Comment: so the incremented value you want is 01:03:00 then?

Comment: yes.01:03:00 is right.  Shell variable too.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `awk`.

```
$ echo 01:02:99 | awk -vINC_BY=1 -F: '{
    $3 += INC_BY; 
    $2 += int( $3 / 100 );
    $1 += int( $2 / 100 );
    printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", $1, $2 % 100, $3 % 100);
}'
01:03:00
```

This assumes that you want to increment by one. Change 'INC_BY' to the value you want to increase the number by.

Using `sed` is [not a good idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36949/addition-with-sed).

Comment: Thanks.  How would I increment it by 'x' amount?

Comment: @djent I've updated the answer

Comment: Thanks again your too kind.  I should've just gotten to the point.  I want to increment the 46 and 48 in the string by x amount. how would that work for:      1
00:00:46,666 --> 00:00:48,751
Eyes on Kahili objective.

Comment: @djent - could you please update the question ?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in bash...

First strip off the `:` to treat it as an integer, then add 1.  Because of leading zero's we need to force base 10.  The syntax would be similar to

```
let x=10#$(echo $x | tr -d :)+1
```

Then we can use `printf` and some `bash` arithmetic to put the `:` back in.

```
printf %02d:%02d:%02d $((x/10000%100)) $((x/100%100)) $((x%100))
```

We can put this together:
e.g.

```
$ x=01:02:99
$ let x=10#$(echo $x | tr -d :)+1
$ x=$(printf %02d:%02d:%02d $((x/10000%100)) $((x/100%100)) $((x%100)))
$ echo $x
01:03:00
```