# Bash script/awk to input and output a CSV file

Tags: text-processing, awk, date

I'm having some trouble creating a bash/awk/sed script that would take a comma-separated CSV file of three columns (firstname, lastname, date of birth), and outputs another CSV file that has the same columns from input with an additional column that shows the difference between the current date and the date of birth in years.

```
$ yourscript <input CSV file> <output CSV file>
```

- `input.csv` may look like this:

  ```
  bob,wag,06/13/1958
  ashley,hay,01/23/1983
  evan,bert,09/11/1972
  ```
- `output.csv` should look like this:

  ```
  bob,wag,06/13/1958,62
  ashley,hay,01/23/1983,37
  evan,bert,09/11/1972,48
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat data
bob,wag,06/13/1958
ashley,hay,01/23/1983
evan,bert,09/11/1972
```

To output in a file named `output-file` and display to STDOUT at the same time:

```
$ awk -v year="$(\date +%Y)" 'BEGIN{FS="/"} {print $0 "," year-$3}' data | tee output-file
bob,wag,06/13/1958,62
ashley,hay,01/23/1983,37
evan,bert,09/11/1972,48
```

Or to just output to the same file:

```
$ awk -v year="$(\date +%Y)" 'BEGIN{FS="/"} {print $0 "," year-$3}' data > output-file
```

Comment: ... and it could be done in other ways, e.g. `perl`. Generally forget `sed` for arithmetics.

Comment: Thank you for this! I would need to append this data as a new column in an output CSV file, how could I do that in the command line format I mentioned after the $ sign?

Comment: @Phillip: for output redirection, just do ` > output-file` at the end f the one liner above. See edit.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @Cbhihe You can actually incorporate calculation of the "current year" into the `awk` call via the `strftime()` function: `awk 'BEGIN{year=strftime("%Y"); FS="/"} ..... '`.

Comment: Noted, this function will come in handy. Does it take into account the month and day in the subtraction?

Comment: @Philip: I added a second answer in response to both AdminBee's comment and your apparent interest in performing more precise time calculations. I use `gawk` or GNU `awk` to write up a small example where instead of showing a time difference in years you have it in days ...

Comment: I can't let the `sed` arithmetic comment go without mentioning https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36959/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Quoting rozcietrzewiacz: "This is a beautiful example (namely _`sed` being used to do arithmetics_ in the link you provide) of what a misconception paired with creativity can breed."  Btw,  I knew the post and I love it in some weird way...

Answer (score 2):

To perform more accurate time computations, you can use `gawk`'s [time and string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) (per @AdminBee's suggestion). Using input data as:

```
$ cat data
bob,wag,06/13/1958
ashley,hay,01/23/1983
evan,bert,09/11/1972
```

You can get a time difference in **days** between now and the date shown on each line, with:

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{today=systime()} 
           {print $0 "," int((today-mktime(substr($3,7,4)" "substr($3,1,2)" "substr($3,4,2)" "00" "00" "00))/(3600*24))}' \
           data | tee output-file

 bob,wag,06/13/1958,22755
 ashley,hay,01/23/1983,13765
 evan,bert,09/11/1972,17551
```

The snippet:

```
int((today-mktime(substr($3,7,4)" "substr($3,1,2)" "substr($3,4,2)" "00" "00" "00))/(3600*24))
```

does three basic things for each line of the input file:

- it calculates the time elapsed (in seconds) since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (on POSIX systems), not counting leap seconds, with `mktime(substr($3,7,4)" "substr($3,1,2)" "substr($3,4,2)" "00" "00" "00)`
- it calculates the time difference between the above quantity and the variable `today`, which contains the number of seconds elapsed at time of execution since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
- it divides the time difference in seconds by 3600*24 to get the same in days, and only consider the integer part of the result, to get whole days with `int()`.

You could play with that to get your time difference in seconds, minutes, hours per your need. HTH

Answer (score 1):

To get the date difference, you can use this small bash function

Use following numbers for your needs

- #To get **Days** difference: 86400
- #To get **Years** difference: 31536000

---

**Bash Function**

```
datediff() {
  current_date=$(date -d "$1" +%s)
  birth_date=$(date -d "$2" +%s)
  echo $(( (current_date - birth_date) / 31536000)) Years
}
```

**Usage:**

```
datediff '9/28/2020' '1/1/1999'
```

**Output:**

```
 21 years
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I'm just not sure how to add a new column to the output CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
perl6 -MText::CSV -e 'my @a = csv( in => $*IN ); my $date = Date.today;  \
       @a>>.[2] = @a.map: *.[2].subst(/ (\d**2) \/ (\d**2) \/ (\d**4) /, {"$2-$0-$1"} ).Date;  \
       @a>>.[3] = @a.map: (($date - *.[2])/365.2425).floor;  \
       csv( in => @a, out => $*OUT );' < file.txt
```

Sample Input (file.txt):

```
bob,wag,06/13/1958
ashley,hay,01/23/1983
evan,bert,09/11/1972
maggie,simpson,05/09/2021
lisa,simpson,05/09/2014
bart,simpson,05/09/2012
```

Sample Output:

```
bob,wag,1958-06-13,63
ashley,hay,1983-01-23,39
evan,bert,1972-09-11,49
maggie,simpson,2021-05-09,1
lisa,simpson,2014-05-09,8
bart,simpson,2012-05-09,10
```

The code above returns `ISO 8601` dates, and uses `ISO 8601` dates to compute years (`floor`ed). Briefly, the `.csv` file is read in and parsed by the `csv(…)` function, made available by loading the `Text::CSV` module at the command line. The data is read into array `@a`, and today's date is recorded as `$date`.

In the second line of code, `subst` is used to analyze the third column and return the date-of-birth in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, which is then converted to an `ISO 8601` date by calling `.Date` on that string. In the third line of code, each `ISO 8601` date-of-birth is subtracted from `$date` today's date, `floor`ed, and returned as an extra column. In the last line of code, valid `.csv` is output.

If `mm/dd/yyyy` dates are required in the output (same as input but NOT `ISO 8601`), then reformat the `ISO 8601` Date with the following command, just before the `csv(in => @a, out => $*OUT)` last command:

```perl
@a>>.[2] = @a.map: *.[2].mm-dd-yyyy("/");
```

---

NOTE: "age-at-date" column is only approximate. The `ISO 8601` dates when subtracted will return accurate **days**, but these are ***inaccurately*** converted to years by dividing by `365.2425` days/year and `floor`ing.

*[The right way to calculate "age-at-date" is to calculate the number of leap-days a person has lived, e.g. using Raku's `is-leap-year` function. It's not clear any answer yet posted has accurately addressed this issue--including mine].*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601
https://docs.raku.org/language/temporal#index-entry-Date_and_time_functions
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you really want:

years difference:

```
(echo "firstname,lastname,d"; cat input.csv) | csv-sqlite \
 "select *, strftime('%Y', 'now') - substr(d, 7, 4) as year_diff
  from input" | csv-header --remove
```

age:

```
(echo "firstname,lastname,d"; cat input.csv) | csv-sqlite
  "select *, strftime('%Y', 'now') - substr(d, 7, 4) -
             case when strftime('%m%d', 'now') >= (substr(d, 1, 2) || substr(d, 4, 2))
             then 0 else 1 end as age
  from input" | csv-header --remove
```

csv-sqlite and csv-header are from [csv-nix-tools](https://github.com/mslusarz/csv-nix-tools)